# Convert local HTML file to PDF with wkhtmltopdf C library

Tags: c++, qt, wkhtmltopdf

I am using the wkhtmltopdf C library to convert a local HTML file to PDF, but no matter what I've tried, it does not successfully convert the file.  Using an external URI (like google.com) works fine, however any local files will fail, either with no error message or with HTTP error codes 1003 or 1302.

Here is the code I am using:

```
wkhtmltopdf_global_settings *globalSettings;
wkhtmltopdf_object_settings *objectSettings;
wkhtmltopdf_converter *converter;

wkhtmltopdf_init(1);

globalSettings = wkhtmltopdf_create_global_settings();
wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(globalSettings, "size.paperSize", "A4");
wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(globalSettings, "orientation", "Portrait");
wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(globalSettings, "colorMode", "Color");
wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(globalSettings, "size.paperSize", "A4");
wkhtmltopdf_set_global_setting(globalSettings, "out", "output.pdf");

converter = wkhtmltopdf_create_converter(globalSettings);

objectSettings = wkhtmltopdf_create_object_settings();

wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(objectSettings, "load.blockLocalFileAccess", "false");


wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(objectSettings, "page", "inputfile.html");

wkhtmltopdf_add_object(converter, objectSettings, NULL);

if (wkhtmltopdf_convert(converter) != 1)
{
    qWarning(qPrintable("Error code: " + QString::number(wkhtmltopdf_http_error_code(converter))));
}

wkhtmltopdf_destroy_converter(converter);
wkhtmltopdf_deinit();
```

I am using QT, and the input file is within a resource file of mine.  I have tried many variation to get wkhtmltopdf to load the file, but none of the following have worked (some liberties have been taken with the below source, but you should get the idea):

I tried to copy the contents of the input file into a QTemporaryFile, and load that file:

```
QTemporaryFile temp;
if (temp.open())
{
    temp.write(inputFile.readAll());
    wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(objectSettings, "page", temp.fileName());
}
```

I tried using the resource file path directly:

```
wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(objectSettings, "page", ":templates/input.html");
```

I've also tried adding in `file://` for the above attempts.  Does anyone have any idea why it may not be working, and if so, how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Qt resource paths will most likely not work. The resource paths are only visible to APIs that internally use `QFile` *and* use the same copy of the Qt library as your code is using.

The approach with temporary files is a decent workaround.

But this line can't really work:

```cpp
wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(objectSettings, "page", temp.fileName());
```

The type that you pass (a `QString`) is wrong. Unfortunately, the interface is C-like and there's no type safety, so you're lulled into complacency. You need to pass it a utf8-encoded file path:

```
wkhtmltopdf_set_object_setting(objectSettings, "page",
                               temp.fileName().toUtf8().constData());
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about passing in a QString.  Unfortunately, when I try your suggestion, the conversion fails with error code 0.  Prepending "file://" yields error code 1003.  Internet searches are turning up nothing for what these error codes mean.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard Given that you're using Qt anyway, why not use `QWebView` directly? It'll be much easier than going through wkhtmltopdf, the latter is really meant to be used from C.

Comment: I am adding this functionality to a library, so there is no QApplication running (a prerequisite, as I understand it, of QPainter and therefore QWebView).

Comment: @AnthonyHilyard You don't need an application running, you just need an instance of it to exist. Make one on the heap and you'll be OK. The makers of wkhtmltopdf had to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using your suggested approach.  I have ditched wkhtmltopdf, and it is working well.